# Wrong mysqli query?

Tags: mysqli

I think I have done a wrong mysqli query because the data is not inserted into the DB, I tried to find the mistake but I couldn't. Can you guys please help me. I also tried to find the mistake with rapidphp but its not working.

Thats my php:

```
if(isset($_POST['addclient']))
{    


   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $last = $_POST['last'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 
   $address = $_POST['address'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $hosting = $_POST['hosting'];
   $hosting_name = $_POST['hosting_name'];
   $hosting_password = $_POST['hosting_password'];
   $registration = $_POST['registration'];
   $notes = $_POST['notes'];


    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($email)) {            
        if(empty($email)) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                                <center>Something went wrong.. </center>
                            </div>";
        }


    } else {    

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO clients (name,last,email,password,address,phone,hosting,hosting_name,hosting_password,registration,notes) 
        VALUES('$name','$last','$email','$password','$address','$phone','$hosting','$hosting_name','$hosting_password',now(),'$notes')");


        echo"<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                                <center>Client successfully updated..</center>
                            </div>";
    }
}
```

I also checked the HTML form it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

in your mysqli_query you have mentioned 'registration' database field name 
    but you have not put the textbox reference which you have taken in variable 
    $registration = $_POST['registration'];
    AND I have also check your code it's working fine, you should check your 
    DataBase connection file.

This is my database connection file :

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
    if($con)
    {
        echo ".";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "not connected";
    }
?>
<?php
include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['addclient']))
{    
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $last = $_POST['last'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password']; 
   $address = $_POST['address'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $hosting = $_POST['hosting'];
   $hosting_name = $_POST['hosting_name'];
   $hosting_password = $_POST['hosting_pass'];
   $registration = $_POST['registration'];
   $notes = $_POST['notes'];

       if(empty($email))
       {            
            if(empty($email))
            {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                    <center>Something went wrong.. </center>
                      </div>";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {   

             $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO clientdata (name,last,email,password,address,phone,hosting,hosting_name,hosting_password,registration,notes) 
            VALUES('$name','$last','$email','$password','$address','$phone','$hosting','$hosting_name','$hosting_password',now(),'$notes')");


            echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                    <center>Client successfully updated..</center>
                  </div>";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>client data</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="containar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <form method="post" class="form-group">
                        <label >Enter FirstName:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="Enter Name..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter LastName:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last"  placeholder="Enter LastName"><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Enter Email..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"  placeholder="Enter Password..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Address:</label>
                        <textarea placeholder="Enter Address..." class="form-control" name="address"  style="width:430px; 
                        height:100"></textarea> <br><br>

                        <label >Enter Mobile Number:</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Hosting:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hosting" placeholder="Enter Hosting..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Hosting Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hosting_name"  placeholder="Enter HostingName..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Hosting Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="hosting_pass"  placeholder="Enter Hosting Password..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Registration:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="registration"  placeholder="Enter Registration..."><br><br>

                        <label >Enter Notes:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notes"  placeholder="Enter Notes...">
                        <br><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="addclient" value="submit" class="class">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
                    </form>
</body>
</html>
```